# How to insert password as Hash to Ms SQL in coldfusion?

Tags: html, css, sql-server, coldfusion

I am creating a form that saves a user registration. I want to insert the password to the database as hash or md5.

This is my html form with few coldfusion codes:

```
        <form id="myForm" class="ui form segment" method="post" action="registeraction.cfm">
      <p>Let's go ahead and get you signed up.</p>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="field">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input  placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input  placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="field">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input  placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
        </div>
      </div>


      <input class="ui blue submit button" type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is the code in registeraction.cfm :

```
<!--- Insert the new record ---> 
<cfinsert datasource="mydatasource" tablename="Users"> 

<h1>User Added</h1> 
<cfoutput> You have added #Form.name# #Form.email# to the testdb database. 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: As suggested by @pete freitag below - please reconsider a better hashing algorithm. I used `bcrypt` as CLR in SQL Server for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you. in registeraction.cfm just create hash and store it in form.password (I would recommend using CFC for any business logic and use cfm for only presentation )

```
  <cfset form.password  = Hash(Form.password, "SHA") > 
   <!--- Insert the new record ---> 
  <cfinsert datasource="mydatasource" tablename="Users"> 

 <h1>User Added</h1> 
 <cfoutput> You have added #Form.name#       #Form.email# to the testdb database. 
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 8):

You should avoid using MD5, it is considered to be a weak algorithm. See:
[How weak is MD5 as a password hashing function ?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function)

In addition you should not just hash the password, you should combine the plain text password with a salt. For more info see: [OWASP: Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 4):

For well known hashings, you can use SQL Server built-in function `HASHBYTES()` - it returns `VARBINARY`

example:

`INSERT INTO dbo.table (Password) VALUES (HASHBYTES('MD5', 'plaintext'))`